# How to get accurate location without internet

Tags: android

I need to get the users location when there is no internet connectivity due to rural locations.

Most of the solutions is ten years old here, I was wondering if there might be a more recent solution.

I have tried to use the fused location manager but it only gets the location once and does not change location when requested again.

So I assume that it holds the last location requested and don't request a new location if you call the method again.

Is there a post or simple solution to get the user location without internet connection.

Perhaps by clicking button or just simply calling a method to get the new location.

```java
public class Location implements LocationListener
{

    //Variables
    private Location location;
    
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    
    private double latitude;
    
    private double longitude;
    
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;  
    
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 4000;
    
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                                this);
                        
        if (locationManager != null)
         {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            
            if (locationManager != null)
            {
              latitude = location.getLatitude();
              longitude = location.getLongitude();
                               
            }
                            
        }
        
    }//End of onCreate

     public void stopUsingGPS()
    {
        if (locationManager != null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GpsTracker.this);
        }
    }
  
  
  
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location)
    {
    
         latitude = location.getLatitude();
         longitude = location.getLongitude();
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider)
    {
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider)
    {
    
    }



}
```

regards

Comment: Use GPS.  Fused is not GPS, its a combo of GPS and network.  Also, post your code so we know you're requesting locations in the right way-  if you're using getLastKnownLocation you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi Gabe, yes I have used  the lastknownlocation. Could you please assist or point me to good example that I can use. All the help is appreciated. I have added the code that I used to get the location.

Comment: LastKnownLocation never updates.  It only serves cached locations from other apps that requested it.  It frequently returns null if the device hasn't asked for location recently.  Use requestLocationUpdates or requestSingleUpdate to actually turn on the location software and get new locations.  LastKnownLocation should only be used in limited circumstances (trying to get a quick location if it exists, to later be replaces by the results of one of the two above).

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for the reply it is much appreciated. May I ask that you just put a simple example on how to get the requestSingleUpdate method.
Regards